# Every Non empty subset has a least element implies linear order

Tags: abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, set-theory, well-orders

Suppose $(A,R)$ be structure where R is a binary relation on $A$.
Suppose $A$ has the property that every Non empty subset of $A$ has a least element w.r.t. the relation $R$. Then $R$ is a linear order on $A$.

*Proof:*

Trichotomy: For any two $x,y \in A$, and $x\neq y$ ,  consider the two elements subset $\{x,y\}$ of $A$.

Anti-Symmetry: Given $x,y \in A$, $x\neq y$ and  $xRy$. Now $yRx$ would imply non existence of least element in $\{x,y\}$.

Transitive: Given $xRy$ and $yRz$.

For $x=y$, it is trivial that $xRz$.

For $x\neq y$:

$x\neq z$, otherwise $yRx$, which contradicts Anti-Symmetry.

Hence by trichotomy, $zRx$ or $xRz$.

For $zRx$ consider the 3-element subset $\{x,y,z\}$, which will not have a least element.
Hence $xRz$.

Thus $R$ is a linear order. $\blacksquare$

**What is wrong with my reasoning?**

This question is inspired by Noah's answer to following question:

[https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703756/the-difference-between-well-order-and-total-order#:~:text=A%20well%2Dordering%2C%20as%20you,itself%20has%20no%20least%20element](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703756/the-difference-between-well-order-and-total-order#:%7E:text=A%20well%2Dordering%2C%20as%20you,itself%20has%20no%20least%20element)).

P.S.: I don't have enough reputation to comment on Noah's answer and ask for clarification.

Comment: Trichotomy usually requires that *exactly one* of $xRy$, $yRx$, and $x=y$ hold. You only proved that at least one does, and that $xRy$ and $yRx$ cannot be the only two that hold. That is not trichotomy. You are going to need to fix something else, because as written your claim would imply that a nonstrict well-order (e.g., $\mathbb{N}$ under $\leq$) is a strict well order, which is false.

Comment: Looking at Noah's answer, I think he said "antisymmetric" when he meant "asymmetric".

Comment: @Arturo. Thank you so much for your help. I got your point $xRx$ and $x=y$ can hold simultaneously. That's not trichotomy. Is it true that with the above premises with additional $R$ being irreflexive, then $R$ is a strict linear ordering.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yes, you are right. He used asymmetry which different from anti-symmetry.

Comment: Your argument that $xRy$ and $yRx$ do not both hold is also wrong. (This is where Noah's assumption of asymmetry comes in). The element $x\in A$ is a least element of $A$ under $R$  if for every $y\in A$, if $x\neq y$ then $xRy$.This definition does not require uniqueness, so the set $\{x,y\}$ with $x\neq y$ would still have a (in fact, two) least element if both $xRy$ and $yRx$ hold. You either need to assume every nonempty subset has a *unique* least element *and* irreflexivity (that will imply asymmetry), or just asymmetry (which implies irreflexivity) as Noah does.

Comment: PS Don't use math mode to produce italic font. Italic font is different from math italic. Use `*text*`

Comment: Thank you so much for insight that least element need not to be unique. Just for the sum up things, can you give a formal statement: under what minimal conditions (A,R), R will be strict linear order given every Non empty subset of A has least element.(P.S. you guys, like you, Noah, Asaf, bof are my superstars. I have learnt lot about basics of set theory from you).

Comment: A counterexample to "every nonempty set has a least element and irreflexive imply linear order" is the two element set $\{x,y\}$ with $R=\{(x,y), (y,x)\}$, for the reason mentioned above this satisfies both conditions, but is not a (strict) order.

Comment: If (i) every nonempty set has a least element; and (ii) $R$ is asymmetric, then $R$ is a linear (in fact, well-) order. Also if (i) every nonempty set has a unique least element; and (ii) $R$ is irreflexive. Probably other combinations as well.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I can't thank you enough for being so generous to me and giving  your precious time to clarify my misunderstanding. (P.S. I don't understand your italic comment, I am new to latex. So can you please explain it with a simple example , ofcourse if you have time)

Comment: Look at the edit I made. You wrote `$Proof$` to get what looks like italic font (actually, what is called "math italic"). That produces this: $Proof$. Instead, you should just write `*Proof*`, which will produce this: *Proof*. This is done outside of latex/mathjax. Any text between `*`s is rendered in italic. Use `**` to get bold text. `**Proof like this**` gives **Proof like this**

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I will keep it in my mind and will not use math italic unnecessarily. Thank you so much.

Comment: See edit I was making while you commented.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have gone through the edit. Thank you so much for being so kind to me and teaching me some basics of latex. I will keep it in mind in my further posts.